# I want to ask (and answer) a question that's a bit of an invitation to argue

Tags: discussion

I have written a few well received answers concerning rice. [Why is cooking rice so complicated?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44030/why-is-cooking-rice-so-complicated/44033#44033); ["Instant" leftover rice? Making leftover-like rice without the wait? (as in for fried rice)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20935/instant-leftover-rice-making-leftover-like-rice-without-the-wait-as-in-for/41289#41289); [Rice gets burnt and watery](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rice-gets-burnt-and-watery/41237#41237); even [How do I get rid of bugs in rice?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43744/how-do-i-get-rid-of-bugs-in-rice/43745#43745) It's not a big surprise, I jump on rice questions because rice is something I know very well.

*Always* somebody comes along and recommends microwaving it.

I like to experiment (you probably have figured that out) so I have tried it several times. I have tried every method I've seen written here or elsewhere to microwave rice. Microwaving rice produces cooked rice that is inferior to the steaming or pilaf method. I even have *pictures* :)

So, I want to ask, "Can I make good rice in the microwave?" At the same time, I'd post an answer (without "accepting" it). "No". I'd show a few pictures. I'd point out it makes good fried rice if cooked in the microwave. I'd also point out that the microwave doesn't necessarily save any time (more pictures).

I'd end the question with a challenge. I'll upvote any answer that provides a method that improves the results of microwaving rice. I'd accept an answer that that actually makes rice that's as good as "traditionally" cooked.

Done this way, the question (and my answer) is likely to inspire argument. I'm hoping that it would also help people to master rice. It ain't rocket surgery.

It's a bit different to go about a Q&A this way. Advice?

EDIT: How about, "Why doesn't microwaved rice taste as good?"

Comment: You really need to start a blog to have your true outlet.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ  Stop trying to get rid of me!

Comment: That would be a more appropriate outlet for the kind of interaction and openness you want.   I am sure you would not be gotten rid of.

Comment: Isn't there a way to contribute to the Seasoned Advice blog? Edit: oh I was thinking about the newsletter I guess? I thought there used to be a blog. I don't see it now though.

Comment: Edit2: Oh there it is. It exists. No new posts though. http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/

Answer (score 6):

I would just ask "how do I make good rice in the microwave?" providing a bit of detail about what you've tried and how it failed, with the assumption that it's possible to make it work somehow.

If you talk to the people who've recommended this method and find out that the quality of rice they can get is the same low quality you've gotten, okay, then you could confidently say the answer is "you can't, it's impossible." But otherwise, posting "it's impossible" is really just an invitation to argue (not constructive), and seems an unnecessary modification of our usual Q&A structure.

Comment: I like that. Same info, different approach. That's what I'll do.

Comment: See the edit to the question, that might bring out answers useful to *me* (and even others who abuse rice in such a terrible way)